# http.request( ) Won't Work In Local Environment With Subdomains

Tags: node.js, express

I'm performing an http.request() to an app running locally, but it's hitting the wrong route, and I can't figure out why...

I believe the problem is with the subdomain not being acknowledged.

I'm currently using `lvh.me:4000` for my development app.  With the subdomain, the full url is `api.lvh.me:4000`

Here is what I have so far.  The `http.request()` keeps hitting the `/*` route and returns html.  What I want is for the app to hit the `/subdomain/api/*` route...

**Server.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        app.use(require('express-subdomain-handler')({
            baseUrl: 'lvh.me:4000',
            logger: false
        }));
}
```

**Routes**

```
    // ------ Handle Missing External API Routes
    app.get('/subdomain/api/*', function(req, res) {
        res.status(404).json({
            name: 'Missing',
            message: 'Resource Not Found - Incorrect Route',
            code: 'missing',
            status: 404
        });
    });

    // ------ Handle Missing Application Routes - Catch-All
    app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
        console.log(req)
        res.status(404).render('404');
    });
```

**External request being performed from another app running locally**

```
    var options = {
        hostname: api.lvh.me,
        port: 4000,
        path: '/missing_resource',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        var body = '';
        // Handle Errors
        if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
            // Aggregate Chunks
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function() {
                return callback(JSON.parse(body), null);
            });
        } else {
            // Aggregate Chunks
            res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                body += chunk;
            });
            // Callback
            res.on('end', function() {
                return callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
            });
        }
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Servant SDK Error', e);
    });

    req.end();
```

Again, the problem here is that the request is hitting `/*` instead of `/subdomain/api/`

Comment: Are you sure that the code inside of your `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {` block is executing?

Comment: 100% Sure.  All other routes without subdomains work perfectly.